# Variable pointing to null again instead of pointing to object

Tags: javascript, webrtc

In the below given code I have created `rtcobj` variable at global scope using `var datatype(initially null assigned)`,but when I am assigning the object `RTCPeerConnection(configuration)`
the variable points to `RTCPeerConnection(configuration)` as long as the function lasts, but afterwards `rtcobj` starts pointing to null again. Why is it happening so I am not getting (Means why `rtcobj` points to null again instead of `rtc` object).

```
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({video:true,audio:true},function(mystream){
                        localvideo.srcObject=mystream;
                        conn.mystream=mystream
                        var configuration = { 
                            "iceServers": [{ "url": "stun:stun2.1.google.com:19302" }]
                        };
                        rtcobj=new RTCPeerConnection(configuration)
                        console.log(rtcobj)
                        rtcobj.addStream(mystream);
                        rtcobj.onaddstream=function(event){
                            otherpeerspan.style.display="none"
                            muteunmute.style.display="block"
                            remotevideo.srcObject=event.stream
                        } 
                        
                        rtcobj.onicecandidate=function(event){
                            if(event.candidate){
                                send({ 
                                    type: "candidate", 
                                    candidate: event.candidate 
                                }); 
                            }
                        }
                    },function (error) { 
                        console.log(error); 
                        }
                    )
                                                                                                                            
                }
                console.log("rtc:"+rtcobj)
```

Comment: Did you call navigator.webkitGetUserMedia() method before checking console.log?

Comment: @Pavan Yes, i have called the method first and then after console.log function is called

Comment: In that case, please check if the file in which your global variable is defined isn't called twice which in turn resets to your default value (null)

Comment: i have checked everything, but unable to fix it

Comment: Difficult for us to give you solution without looking into code execution. If you could provide a jsfiddle reproducible bug, we can try to help you

Comment: as it's global variable, please check if rtcobj was defined somewhere else in your project.